# Rails 3 : How to disable autosave of has_one and has_many associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a user model which has one
image. how can i disable the autosave option. when i tried the following i am getting an error. 
Am using rails 3.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :image_mapping, :class_name=>"ImageMapping",:as => :imageable  
  has_one :image, :through => :image_mapping, :class_name => "Image", :autosave => false  
end
```

It says Unknown key(s): autosave
isn't loading autosave_association.rb properly?

Comment: Are you sure you're using ActiveRecord 3.x? Can you provide a trace of your error?

Comment: Why are you using the `:as` option? Also, you don't need to specify the `class_name` if rails can deduce it automatically from the association-name.

Comment: You could also tag this `activerecord`, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably doesn't solve your problem, but perhaps you find it helpful anyway:

There seems to be a problem with `has_one :through`.  For example in `class Post`,

```
has_one :owner, :through => :blog
```

works fine, but

```
has_one :owner, :through => :blog, :autosave => false
```

doesn't.  If you instantiate a `Post`, like so

```
post = Post.find 1
```

you get this:

```
ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): autosave
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:43:in `assert_valid_keys'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1758:in `create_has_one_through_reflection'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1102:in `has_one'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:137:in `has_one'
[...]
```

Looking at [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), I can't find a reason why it shouldn't work.  And in fact it seems to work fine with `has_many`, only `has_one` hiccups if the `:autosave` option is set.

Unless somebody here on Stack Overflow finds something wrong with using `:has_one` in this way, you could also go to the [Rails mailing list](http://lists.rubyonrails.org/mailman/listinfo) for help; I think Rails-core is the right one for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to assign an object to a has_one association without saving it, use the build_association method. The object being replaced will still be saved to update its foreign key.

> Example

```
user = User.new
user.build_image
```